# How to get 2 random numbers divisible by each other?

Tags: javascript

I'm generating 2 random numbers:

1) The first number must be random from 1 to 30

2) The second number must be random from 1 to 10

I'm simply trying to have the first number divisible by the second number or vice-versa, and finally, alert the result. My question is how to get the result of the division of 2 random numbers? Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot in advance!.

**Note:** the first number must be divisible by the second number.

Here's my code:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    do {
    var firstRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*30) + 1;
    var secondRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*10) + 1;
    if(firstRandomNumber % secondRandomNumber === 0){
        correctResult = result;
        arr.push(correctResult);
    }
    } while ((firstRandomNumber % secondRandomNumber === 0));
  }
  console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You have both: `first number divisible by the second number or vice-versa` and `first number must be divisible by the second number` which is not especially clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things:

- Your `while` loop should be looping until `firstRandomNumber % secondRandomNumber === 0`, so you want to just keep looping while it's not true.
- `result` isn't set anywhere, so I added the result in the array
- The `if(firstRandomNumber % secondRandomNumber === 0){` is redundant. When the do/while loop completes, it will have the do numbers that matched. Simply move the `arr.push()` outside that loop.

```js
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  do {
    var firstRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*30) + 1;
    var secondRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*10) + 1;
  } while ((firstRandomNumber % secondRandomNumber !== 0));

  console.log('first', firstRandomNumber, 'second', secondRandomNumber);
  arr.push(firstRandomNumber / secondRandomNumber);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: can you update your answer to only add ONE element to the array (the result of the division) and also console out the 2 numbers that are being divided with each other? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @progx I added the `console.log`, and the div result is already adding to the array. Just remove the for loop if you only want one number.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help bro!!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a more functional approach: create a function that creates two random numbers, and returns them if one is divisible by the other. Then, just call that function until you get a truthy result:

```js
function tryGetDivisible() {
  var firstRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 1;
  var secondRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  if (firstRandomNumber % secondRandomNumber === 0) {
    console.log(firstRandomNumber, secondRandomNumber);
    return firstRandomNumber / secondRandomNumber;
  }
}

let result;
while (!result) result = tryGetDivisible();
const arr = [result];
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Tossed you an upvote. This is a solid answer as well, and the loop is a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler approach is to get the first random number, and then try getting the second random number until they are divisible. So here will be the code:

```
    var firstRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*30) + 1;
    while (firstRandomNumber % secondRandomNumber !== 0) {
        var secondRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*10) + 1;
    }
  console.log(firstRandomNumber + "," + secondRandomNumber);
```

Comment: your answer does not work if the first random number is 29, because then the second number will be to be only 1 or 29.

Comment: Still 29 is divisible by both 1 and 29. The same way 4 is divisible by 2. Unless this is an extra condition you want to have in your code, it meets your need.

Answer (score 0):

Since the first must be divisible by the second, my approach would be:

1. Generate the second number.
2. Determine the maximum multiple of the second number that is no more than 30 (e.g., `Math.floor(30/firstNumber)`).
3. Select a multiple at random and use that as the first number. You simply need to select a random number between 1 and the largest allowed multiplier (inclusive).

This way, there's no need to do a generate-and-test loop, which could go on an unbounded number of times before a successful pair is generated.

Comment: Wouldn't this make the first number dependent on the second number? It wouldn't be truly random: For example if the second number was prime, then 1 would always be picked for the first number.

Comment: @FrankerZ - It's already dependent on the second number, since there's a requirement to reject all first numbers that are not multiples of the second number. The generate-and-test loops simply disguise the dependence.

Comment: The randomness would not be as good as it could be. For example if the first number is 8, this method only allows for 16 and 24 as the second number when in fact, 2, 1, and 4 should be possibilities.

Comment: @MarkMeyer - Did I misread the question? OP specifically said "the first number must be divisible by the second number". Also, note that I'm generating the second number (the one constrained to be between 1 and 10) first.

Comment: @TedHopp:  you're right, although it also says 'first number divisible by the second number or vice-versa' so I suppose it's not clear.

Comment: @MarkMeyer - Good point. If it's the former, then your answer may be the best, although I'd have to think about possible bias.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the `while` loop, you can pick the first number, then assemble the possible second numbers in an array. Then randomly pick one of these:

```js
let first = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1

// all possible divisible numbers
let factors = Array.from({length: 30}, (_, i) => i + 1)
    .filter(i => first % i === 0 || i % first === 0)

//pick one
let second = factors[Math.floor(Math.random() * factors.length)]

console.log(first, second)
```